# Why isn't my Unity animation not working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game for a game jam and I have a script where the teeth of the shark regrow. But this only seems to work one time.

```
        if (CurrentBossHealth == 675)
        {
            StartCoroutine(RegenTeeth());
            bubble.Phase2 = true;
            ControlPhase2 = true;
        }
        
        if (CurrentBossHealth == 450)
        {
            StartCoroutine(RegenTeeth());
            Phase3.enabled = true;
            ControlPhase3 = true;         
        }
        
        if (CurrentBossHealth == 225)
        {
            StartCoroutine(RegenTeeth());
            bubble.Phase4 = true;
            Phase3.SpawnRate = 7f;
            ControlPhase4 = true;
        }

  private IEnumerator RegenTeeth()
    {
        FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("Roar");
        animator.SetBool("Regen", true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        t1.RespawnTooth();
        t2.RespawnTooth();
        t3.RespawnTooth();
        t4.RespawnTooth();
        t5.RespawnTooth();
        t6.RespawnTooth();
        t7.RespawnTooth();
        t8.RespawnTooth();
        t9.RespawnTooth();
    }
```

It only plays the animation for health = 675, after that it doesn't work.
[This is my animator if it helps. RegenTooth is the animation that should be playing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fa699.png)

Comment: Are you sure the other if blocks are being entered?

Comment: Yes. After the regen animation it lets you do the attack animation which is only possible if it’s gone back to idle